# awesome_nested_set gem lft does't have default

Tags: awesome-nested-set

Hey folks I'm experimenting with the ruby awesome_nested_set gem for the first time.

I'm having an issue with my minitests in a rails-api app. I know what the issue is but am unsure how to fix it at this point.

When I run "rails test" I get a bunch of errors similar to the following:
StoresControllerTest#test_should_create_store:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'lft' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO categories (name, created_at, updated_at, id, store_id) VALUES ('MyString', '2018-02-23 03:
08:13', '2018-02-23 03:08:13', 980190962, 980190962)

Here is my Migration:
class AddLftToCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0] def change add_column :categories, :lft, :integer, :null => false add_index :categories, :lft end end

I believe the issue is a result of my migration setting ":lft, :null => false. This makes the most sense, but how can I fix this? Do I need to add something to my fixture, or is there something else I must do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after reading the docs for the gem, it’s apparent that your migration is incomplete. your category needs to have a :rgt column as well as the :lft, :name, and :parent_id for the gem to work. see the docs here: (https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/blob/master/README.md). you also need to add `acts_as_nested_set` to your model for these fields to be populated by the gem.

Comment: Unfortunately I already have all that.

Running via Spring preloader in process 13499
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.6)
2.4.1 :001 > Category.new
 => #<Category id: nil, name: nil, store_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, lft: nil, rgt: nil
, parent_id: nil, depth: 0, children_count: 0>
2.4.1 :002 >

Comment: I think its fixed for now.  I guess I just had to tell the fixture the correct format of the data with the following:



one:
  id: 1
  name: Top Level
  lft: 1
  rgt: 10
child_1:
  id: 2
  name: Child 1
  parent_id: 1
  lft: 2
  rgt: 3